# How do I find my firewall is blocking mysql?

Tags: mysql, firewall

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I couldn't able to connect to mysql via my programming language.

I know all my property file in my code is correct. But still I couldn't able to connect to mysql. I guess my firewall is blocking me out.

I have `ufw` firewall installed, how do I enable 3306 port in that?

I tried these [steps](http://concisedeveloper.com/linux/how-to-open-mysql-port/) but doesn't get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you guess your firewall is blocking you out? How are you trying to connect to mysql? Copy-paste the commands you tried and the complete error messages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use these commands to allow port 3306 through UFW

```
 sudo ufw allow out 3306/tcp  

 sudo ufw allow in 3306/tcp
```

And to check that the rules have been added

```
 sudo ufw status
```

Answer (score 10):

Create the file `/etc/ufw/applications.d/mysql-server` and include the following content.

```
[MySQL]
title=MySQL Relational Database Server
description=MySQL is a Relational Database Server commonly used in a variety of ways including to host the database of websites
ports=3306/tcp
```

Run command:
`sudo ufw allow MySQL`

You should be good to go. Feel free to give it a better title and description. I just tossed something in quick like.